# Absolute positioning of content in responsive full screen slider with respect to row width

Tags: slider, zurb-foundation

I have a full width slider with background image. Slider height is responsive based on the image, so it always shows 100 % of the image from side to side of the screen.

Now I'm trying to position content (text) inside the slider so it is within the content grid and it is on the bottom of the slider.

Desired outcome:

[image: Desired outcome]

The problem is `.medium-6 .columns` that has 0 px height and I'm not able to position its content to the bottom.

CodePen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MaYOgQ

HTML:

```
<div class="slide">
  <div class="height-wrapper">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="columns small-6 small-offset-6">
        <div class="slider-content">
          <h2>Headline</h2>
          <p>Description text</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.slide {
  background-image: url('img/slider1.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  max-height: 627px; /* img full size height */
}

.height-wrapper {
  display: block;
  padding-bottom: 35%; /* hack to always show full height of the image: (img height / img width) */
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
}

.columns {
  position: relative;
}

.slider-content {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 10%;
}

/* The rest is standard Foundation grid code */

.row {
  margin: 0px auto;
  max-width: 62.5em;
  width: 100%;
}
.columns {
  padding-left: 0.9375em;
  padding-right: 0.9375em;
  float: left;
}
.small-6 {width: 50%;}
.small-offset-6 {margin-left: 50% !important;}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mentioned you want to position the elements within slider. I suppose it's a JavaScript slider so you wouldn't mind the positioning done also in JavaScript.

The script calculates what should be the slide height based on the original image size and user's window width. Then it sets the calculated height to `.height-wrapper` element.

Updated CodePen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VaEbOK

I loaded the original Foundation Framework CSS and JS files to the Pen as your Foundation grid excerpt was not complete.

JavaScript:

```
// -- Set slider content HEIGHT --
$(window).on('resize', function() {
  var width = 1900; // Image width
  var height = 627; // Image height
  var slide_height = $(window).width() / (width / height);
  $(".height-wrapper").height(slide_height);
}).trigger('resize');
```

HTML:

```
<div class="slide">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="height-wrapper columns small-6 small-offset-6">
      <div class="slider-content">
        <h2>Headline</h2>
        <p>Description text</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.slide {
  background-image: url('http://placehold.it/1900x627');
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  max-height: 627px;  /* img full size height */
}

.height-wrapper {
  padding: 0; /* remove Foundation .columns padding */
}

.columns {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.slider-content {
  border: 1px solid red;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 10%;
}

// + Foundation Framework
```